# Match multiple whitespace separated strings on lines starting with hash (#)

Tags: php, regex

I want to match the parameters on the following line with a regex:

```
...
# MHz  S  MA  R 50
...
```

With `^#\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s`, I can match the line and the first parameter, but not the others.

See [my example here](https://regex101.com/r/pL4wB7/1).

Comment: which lang you're running?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pL4wB7/2

Comment: I am using pcre (php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\S` to match a non-whitespace character and repeat the captures necessary amount of times:

```
^#\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD3yK0/1)

The values will get into captured groups.

Or, you can get all of them as matches with

```
(?:^#|(?<!^)\G)[ ]*([^\s\n]+)(?=.*$)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD3yK0/4)

Comment: Note that my first solution is unversal, but depends on a constant number of values to capture, and the second one is almost universal since most languages (excep Java, Python and JavaScript) support it via PCRE/Oniguruma, and even .NET also supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Use following `regex`:

```
^#\s+[\w\s]+
```

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pL4wB7/2)

Answer (score 0):

You have a repeating pattern of whitespace followed by non-whitespace that you want to capture, so this should do the trick:

```
`^#(?:\s*(\S+))+$`
```

Sample:

```
var re = new Regex(@"^#(?:\s*(\S+))+$");
var matches = re.Matches("# MHz  S  MA  R 50");
Console.WriteLine(matches);
```

Output:

[image]